# How to set as attribute an attribute value from another class in Python

Tags: python, class, attributes

Imagine having a class

```
class Bracings:  
     def __init__(self,type,axes,matrix):      
         self.type = type  
         self.axes = axes
         self.matrix = matrix

class Element:  
 ...
```

Then, imagine having

```
**elm** = *Element*()  
**br** = *Bracings*( 'buckling' , 'y', [1,2,3,4] )
```

What I want to do is to create an attribute at `elm` which will be like this

```
**elm**.bracing.buckling.y = **br**
```

the problem is i dont know the attributes names... it could be `buckling`, it could be `lateral_tortional`, it could be `y`, it could be `z` they take their values from the **br** object

How would you go about to solve this?

Comment: I'm confused are you trying to create a variable for a list of all the attributes from br or are you trying to use the attributes from br in elm?

Comment: what i am trying to do is use some of the values of the attributes from a br object as attributes in the elm object

Comment: May you give ``Element`` code? Because I don't know what ``elm.bracing`` is (and ``elm.bracing.buckling``).

Comment: elm.bracing is a new attribute of elm i want to create. that attribute i want to have as attributes the values of the attributes of a Bracings instance

Comment: could you give us another example please it's really hard to understand what your asking. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all you have to create a new class which will be empty. then you have to set a function at Element like set_bracings:

```
class Empty(object):  
    def __init__(self):  
        pass

#then at class Element:
class Element:
....
    def set_bracings(self, bracing):
        case = bracing.case
        axes = bracing.axes

        if hasattr(self,'bracings') == False:
            #Its the first ever bracing which is created
            empty1 = Empty()
            setattr( empty1, axes, bracing)
            empty2 = Empty()
            setattr( empty2, case, empty1)
            setattr( self, 'bracings', empty2)
        else:
           if hasattr(self.bracings,case) == False:
                #if we enter in this check then at some point another attribute of case was created, so we keep it
                brace = self.bracings

                empty1 = Empty()
                setattr( empty1, axes, bracing)
                setattr( brace, case, empty1)
                setattr( self, 'bracings', brace)
            else:
                #If we enter here then we our 'case' is the same as another 'case' that was created earlier so we have to keep it
                brace = self.bracings
                old_axes = getattr(self.bracings , case)
                setattr( old_axes, axes, bracing)
                setattr( brace, case, old_axes)
                setattr( self, 'bracings', brace)

#after that you only have to do
elm.set_bracings( br )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are trying to explore the inheritance concept. More information in the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html)

Defining class Element as subclass of Bracing will allow you to access attributes of Bracing from Element.

```
class Element(Bracing):
```

Comment: No, i am not trying to do that. i want the VALUES of the attributes of a Bracings instance to be used as attributes of an Element class instance

Comment: I think that in that case you would like to create either if condition or subclass for each possible value of Bracings instance.